# Is a sequence a frame iff it spans the space?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, frame-theory

Let $(v_k)_k\subseteq V$ be a sequence of vectors in some vector space $V$ which form a [*frame*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_(linear_algebra)). This means that there are constants $0< A\le B<\infty$ such that, for all $v\in V$, we have
$$A \| v\|^2 \le \sum_k |\langle v_k,v\rangle|^2 \le B \|v\|^2.$$
In ([Casazza 2013](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-8176-8373-3_1)) ([Link to pdf](https://framerc.missouri.edu/sites/default/files/pub-files/introduction_to_finite_frame_theory.pdf)) the authors mention (Lemma 2 in page 14) that a family of vectors is a frame *iff* they are a spanning set for the vector space.

Very briefly, the reported proof is as follows:

1. If $(v_k)_k$ does not span $V$, then there is some $x\in V$ such that $\langle v_k,x\rangle=0$ for all $k$, hence we don't have a lower frame bound and thus we don't have a frame.
2. If $(v_k)_k$ is not a frame, then there is a sequence $(x_n)_n$ of normalised vectors such that $\sum_k |\langle v_k,x_n\rangle|^2<1/n$. Hence the limit $x$ of a convergent subsequence of $(x_n)_n$ satisfies $\langle x,v_k\rangle=0$ for all $k$, hence $(v_k)_k$ does not span the set.

While the first part is fine, I have some issues with the second side of the proof. More specifically, the authors seem to be saying that if $(v_k)_k$ is not a frame, then there's no lower frame bound, hence they show how to find a vector not in the span of the sequence.
But why can we make this implication? Couldn't it be possible that $(v_k)_k$ is not a frame for lack of an *upper* frame bound instead? That is, a situation where there is a lower frame bound $A>0$, but no finite upper $B$.

If this is in fact an actual imprecision in the proof, what's a good alternative way to prove this fact (assuming the statement itself does indeed hold)?

Comment: At a first glance, I share your doubt.

Comment: Looks like the article deals with a finite set of vectors in a finite dimensional space. For a counterexample in the infinite dimensional case, see the wikipedia page you linked.

Comment: @MorA. you're saying there is no problem for finite frames? As in, every finite sequence gives a finite upper frame bound? That would make sense. But what's a good way to include this fact in the proof? Also, what do you mean with "counterexample in the infinite dimensional case"? Counterexample to the existence of upper frame bound or to the statement at hand?

Comment: ah, I think I found what you mean. Something like $\{(1,0),(0,1), (0,1/\sqrt2),...\}$ is a spanning set that's not a frame. Hence the statement only works for finite frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space with complex inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$.

**Remark:** In the paper, a frame is a finite collection of vectors satisfying your property.

Let $(v_k)_{k=1}^m =: \mathcal{V} \subseteq V$ be a subset of vectors. Define the corresponding "frame map"
$$T_{\mathcal{V}} : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \ \ T_{\mathcal{V}}(x) := \sum_{k=1}^m |\langle v_k, x\rangle|^2$$
I'll abbreviate this map as $T$.

We say that $\mathcal{V}$ is a frame if there are constants $0 < A \leq B$ so that

$$ A \|v\|^2 \leq T(v) \leq B \|v\|^2.$$

**Goal:** $\mathcal{V}$ is a frame iff $\text{Span}(\mathcal{V}) = V.$

Your argument works if we can show the following lemma.

**Lemma:** If $\mathcal{V}$ is not a frame, then $\inf \{ T(x) \ | \ \|x\| = 1\} = 0.$

**Proof:** Notice by [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) that if $\|x\| = 1$ then

$$ T(x) = \sum_{k=1}^m |\langle v_k, x \rangle|^2 \leq \sum_{k=1}^m \|v_k\|^2.$$

Set

$$B := \sum_{k=1}^m \|v_k\|^2 < \infty.$$

Then for any $v \in V$ we have

$$ B \geq T\left(\frac{v}{\|v\|}\right) = \frac{T(v)}{\|v\|^2} \implies T(v) \leq B \|v\|^2.$$

So the only way that $\mathcal{V}$ can fail to be a frame is if $\inf\{T(x) \ | \ \|x\| =1 \} = 0,$ i.e. we cannot find an $A > 0$. $\blacksquare$

**Remark:** Notice this lemma fails when dealing with infinite frames.

Comment: ah, interesting. So you're saying a finite sequence in finite dimensions is a frame *iff* it has a lower frame bound. And the proof is that by Cauchy-Schwarz, $T(x)= \langle x,Sx\rangle\le B \|x\|^2$ for some finite $B$ (here $S$ is the frame operator, $T$ your operator), hence there is always automatically an upper frame bound. Checks out!

Comment: Yep! I was also doubting it until I saw finite frames.